# error: EXC_BREAKPOINT {code=1, subcode=0x18ee3c5c0}

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, swift3, ios10

I have problem with error. In theory this is breakpoint but I don't any.

```
0x18ee3c5a8 <+324>: b      0x18d9b2f20               ; objc_msgSend
0x18ee3c5ac <+328>: adrp   x8, 145858
0x18ee3c5b0 <+332>: add    x8, x8, #2296             ; =2296 
0x18ee3c5b4 <+336>: adrp   x9, 853
0x18ee3c5b8 <+340>: add    x9, x9, #2656             ; =2656 
0x18ee3c5bc <+344>: str    x9, [x8, #8]
-> 0x18ee3c5c0 <+348>: brk    #0x1
0x18ee3c5c4 <+352>: brk    #0x1
0x18ee3c5c8 <+356>: brk    #0x1
```

My app works when I use it on iPhone alone, but when I test it using Xcode and iPhone bug appers. Always in the same place. Sometimes after 5s sometimes after fiew minutes.

[What XCode show me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTbzb.png)

Comment: You should come up with a short reproducible example showing the Swift code where this error is observed if you want a better chance to have your question answered.

Comment: This error is always in CoreFoundation`CFHash and Xcode show me only this.
In console I have only "(lldb)" and nothing more.

Comment: Clean installation from Xcode gives me working app. I create some CoreData and connect to server. Second installation creates this bug after few seconds, but... When i use app after disconnect from MacBook it's works again! 
To debug program i need to uninstall my app from iPhone and then instal again. I can't just run from Xcode build and reinstall like before.